# Generate tag links of search pattern in Vimwiki

Tags: substitute, plugin-vimwiki

##### Question

How to use `:VimwikiGenerateTagLink` with a search pattern?

##### Explanation

- The Vimwiki command `:VimwikiGenerateTagLinks` produces the list of tags and links of your wiki. Without arguments, it generates the full list of tags and the corresponding links. With arguments, it can report the links of every argument; every argument being a tag.
- You can easily autocomplete tags in `:` command mode.
- However, I don't find the way to pass the argument of a search pattern. For instance, `:VimwikiGenerateTagLinks *` produces a literal `== * ==` header.

##### Use case

Suppose you have four tags:`:2024-01-01:` `:2024-01-02:` `:aaa:` `bbb` and you want to report *only* the tags *not* containing dates, i.e. only `:aaa:` `bbb`. My ideal scenario would be something like

```
:VimwikiGenerateTagLinks [Not-beginning-with-number]+[any-character]
```

or

```
:VimwikiGenerateTagLinks [^0-9].*
```

(Forgive the bad regex use).

Comment: I had a look at the code and it seems not possible with the current implementation. I suppose you have to make a demand to the plugin manager or implement it your self :-).

Comment: Use the plugin's documentation/issue tracker.

Comment: Thanks @VivianDeSmedt. I don't know how to implement it, but I will ask the maintainers of the plugin about it.

Comment: I have proposed an implementation that seems to work reasonably fine :-)

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the VimWiki API you could do something like:

```
function! GenerateTagLinksRegex(regex)
  let tags = vimwiki#tags#get_tags()
  echom '^' .. a:regex .. '$'
  call filter(tags, {i, tag -> (match(tag, '^' .. a:regex .. '$') >= 0)})
  if len(tags) == 0
    return
  endif
  call call('vimwiki#tags#generate_tags', [1] + tags)
endfunction

command! -nargs=1 GenerateTagLinksRegex call GenerateTagLinksRegex(<f-args>)
```